# Passing data from view to controller in yii

Tags: php, ajax, yii, view, controller

I have a text field in my view and I want to pass the value of textbox to the controller, but I don't know how to do it.

I have tried googling it but it only gives ides about passing data from conntroller to view in  yii, so please give an example of doing this with ajax.

Comment: use ajax for that or else do a form submit by specifying the action to the form.

Comment: This will help you http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: what would be the `url` in this situation and how to get that data in `controller`?

Comment: url must be the url of your controller/action and you can get all the data in $_POST variable in the specified action

Comment: thnx deepu for $_POST

Answer (score 1):

follow the steps:

in form:

```
<div class="form-group">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'order_id', array('class' => 'control-label col-lg-4')); ?>
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'order_id',array('class' => 'form-control',
    'ajax' =>
        array('type'=>'POST',
            'url'=>$this->createUrl('recieveValue'), // write in controller this action
            'update'=>'#price',
            'data'=>array('order_id'=>'js:this.value'),
        )

    )); ?>
</div>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'order_id'); ?>
```

In controller:

```
public function actionRecieveValue(){
echo $_POST['order_id'];
}
```

At the top of same controller:

```
array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update','recieveValue'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
),
```

Explanation:

Here text field id is `order_id`, controller action is `recieveValue`what I wrote in the ajax URL as `'url'=>$this->createUrl('recieveValue'),`. Go to the controller and write action name as `actionRecieveValue` just add action before `recieveValue`. Now go to the top of the controller in the method `accessRules` and allow it `recieveValue` into array. Now check through firebug console. Type something into the text box and move the mouse from the textbox. You will find that your textbox value will be recieved into the controller.